# Fast Select from a table with ~300 columns with about 200 mil static rows

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds-aurora

I have a table with around 300+ columns which contain Demographics data with various attributes like Name, Address, State, Zipcode, Sex, education etc.
The table has around 200mil rows. The table never gets updates or inserts and the data is always static unless it is refreshed, which happens once in 6 months, for which we delete the entire table and re-import it from `AWS S3 bucket`.
Right now, the table is on `Postgresql 13.6` which is launched on AWS RDS (Aurora Serverless).

The only operation that is performed on this table/database is `Select` which is extremely slow (5-8 mins) when 4 or more conditions are applied.

There is one index applied and the table is partitioned, by range, into 22 tables using `Zip` as range. All columns have datatype as `text`. i have tried using appropriate data types but there is no improvement in query time.

Explain Analyse always shows sequential scan even when index scan can be used.

```
AWS Aurora size : Serverless v2 (30 - 128 ACUs)
Engine version : 13.6
All other AWS parameters set to default
```

I need help in determining if there would be a better approach to storing this data for milliseconds access and whether going with postgresql on AWS was the right choice.

<s>Unfortunately I cannot paste the full table structure or any example query.</s>

**Update** : Added table schema.I have removed some columns, but they are of the same type. please follow the below link (Thanks @Vérace)

https://paste.depesz.com/s/bn

`Select count(*) from pubdata` this query takes 11 seconds and uses index scan

`count : 255116641`

the below query uses only 3 parallel workers and takes about 5 mins (which is unacceptable it seems)

https://explain.depesz.com/s/1Gam

**Update 2**
I have made the following changes to PostgreSQL parameters

```
max_worker_processes : 20
max_parallel_workers : 10
max_parallel_workers_per_gather : 10
force_parallel_mode : true
```

I am still not looking at significant performance improvements.
the RDS Aurora minimum config is 30ACUs (60 GiB RAM) and can go upto 128 ACUs (256 GiB)

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot get an answer if you don't tell us any details. Whoever wants to keep this a secret will have to spend money to hire a consultant.

Comment: Just point me in a direction. @LaurenzAlbe it would be great help

Comment: https://www.depesz.com/ - you can obfuscate your query plans!

Comment: Can you provide at least the type of `WHERE` clauses you are using and how many columns are selected at a time?  Partitioning by ZIP (or at all) is probably a bad idea and not helping much. What are the keys?

Comment: Why can't you show the table structure and obfuscate all the column names? This is not answerable without basic details.

Comment: Besides what everyone else said, how many rows do you normally `SELECT` at one time, roughly? How many columns do you normally `SELECT` at one time, roughly? What are your index definitions?...do they match your predicates (`JOIN`, `WHERE`, `HAVING`) clauses?

Comment: i am currently editing my answer to include the table schema with some columns removed.
@J.D. it is not fixed and the select can have any number of `WHERE` clauses as well as `GROUP BY` and other stuff. there is only one table so no `JOINS`

Comment: @RohitAgre Are your queries not staticly coded (besides parameters) or are you generating dynamic SQL every time?

Comment: There is an interface to select various "filters" these filters add the required conditions to the where clause.
for example, someone can choose to find all rows which are located in a particular State with certain educational qulaification who own a home and have 2 kids and are "Male"

Comment: Have you tried increasing `work_mem` to, say, 1GB? There’s a disk sort in your explain that might be abysmally slow on RDS (and why was timing turned off in the explain?).

Comment: i have increased it to 20GB @dwhitemv i am looking at a 25% improvement

Comment: Good to know it helps. If you have the resources it would be a good test to make a unpartitioned version of the table and see if searching one table is faster than searching 22. You’re not the first to try to optimize tables backing a customer facing query engine, try researching related questions here.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a table with around 300+ columns ...
> The table has around **200mil** rows.
> There is **one index** applied ...
> ... and the table is partitioned, by range, into 22 tables using Zip ...

Most queries will only be able to *Table Scan* the whole thing.
The only ones that *won't* are the ones based on the field(s) in that *one* index.  Even those based on `Zip` will probably perform poorly because partitioning a five-digit number across 22 partitions makes it pretty poor discriminator.

(Analyse what your Users do and then) Add indexes that support the commonest queries.  You might find that the same two or three criteria keep recurring in many queries.  if so, create a composite index on those.
Or you could do what some, commercial packages do and index *every* column individually.  That way, if a particular index *just happens* to be "useful" for a particular query, then Bingo!  That one will run half-decently.

Even with that in place, PostgreSQL may still only try to use just one index per query and then "muddle through" the rest of it.  The only way around *that* is to completely restructure your queries, to retrieve row ids based on a single criteria, join all of those on the row id and then retrieve the complete dataset based on those ids.
But that's pretty heavy-weight stuff.

```
select 
  t1.id 
, t1.field1 
, t2.field2 
from 
( select 
    id 
  , field1 
  from table1 
  where field1 = ?
) t1 
inner join 
( select 
    id
  , field2 
  from table1 
  where field2 = ?
) t2 
on t1.id = t2.id 
;
```